# Load Facebook friends information using Android

Tags: android, facebook, listview

In my application I am integrating with Facebook and I do:

Log in Facebook and get all information of friends and display it in a List View. It will take a time to do this if the user have a number of friends.

So, is there any way to get information of friend in fixed number sequentially. Suppose I want to get the information for the first 10 friends and display it in a list view and further the next 10.

My list view should be updated in a background task and should working smoothly.

Comment: see : [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use some already made API or JAR file for Facebook integration.

I just have found one [FBRocket](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-facebook-api-example-using-fbrocket) and the [documentation file](http://www.xeomax.net/fbrocket/release/0.1a/doc/) for it. You can see that it has two functions. One is **List getFriendUIDs()** and the second is **List getFriends(String[] uids)**.

And you can get a list of friends for as many UIDs you wish at a time. And from that the [Friend](http://www.xeomax.net/fbrocket/release/0.1a/doc/) object can get information about a friend and use it in your application.

Comment: @MIRRA have you tried this solution before you accepted the answer..? cause i have just searched for things..didnt implemented so.. i dont know whether it solves the problem or not.?